# Помогите с печатью C#

Tags: c#

У меня есть ListBox, в котором выводятся документы.

Код:

```
private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\Snegan\Desktop");
        FileInfo[] files = dinfo.GetFiles("*.docx");
        foreach (FileInfo filenames in files)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(filenames);
        }

    }
```

Как из ListBox отправить в печать документ, который выделен  в ListBox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того чтоб при двойном клике в списке происходила отправка на печать, вы можете использовать следующий код. Метод **PrintDocxFile** по факту вызывает печать любого файла, а не только DOCX, но так как вы не уточнили как именно должна происходить печать (например нужен диалог выбора страниц), я написал обычную отправку на печать независимо от типа файла.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Путь к директории с файлами
        /// </summary>
        public const string FILE_DITECTORY_PATH = @"C:\Users\Snegan\Desktop";

        /// <summary>
        /// Конструктор формы
        /// </summary>
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //Подписываемся на событие загрузки формы и двойной клик по ListBox
            Load += OnLoaded;
            listBox1.DoubleClick += ListBoxOnDoubleClick;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// По двойному клику на ListBox вызываем печать выбранного файла
        /// </summary>
        private void ListBoxOnDoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var selectedFileName = listBox1.SelectedItem?.ToString();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedFileName))
            {
                var filePath = Path.Combine(FILE_DITECTORY_PATH, selectedFileName);
                PrintDocxFile(filePath);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Вызов печати DOCX файла по указанному пути
        /// </summary>
        private void PrintDocxFile(string filePath)
        {
            var info = new ProcessStartInfo(filePath);
            info.Verb = "Print";
            info.CreateNoWindow = true;
            info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            Process.Start(info);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// После окончания загрузки формы получаем весь список файлов в директории
        /// </summary>
        private void OnLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(FILE_DITECTORY_PATH);
            FileInfo[] files = dinfo.GetFiles("*.docx");
            foreach (FileInfo filenames in files)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(filenames);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Дополнительные сведения: Не удается найти указанный файл

Comment: @Snegan, FILE_DITECTORY_PATH в данной константе указывается путь к папке. P.S. Поправил пример под ваш путь.

Comment: поправил, проверил на отдельной форме, всё работает, сейчас буду инкулидть в основную) Спасибо!

Comment: @Snegan, пожалуйста)